# What does the word "render" means in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to read a definitive guide to django. But I can't get feel of the word 'render', which I encounter template chapter in book. Author have never referred to meaning of it, even if I have read a introductory template chapter.

In english dictionary, render is

```
to cause to be or become; make: to render someone helpless.
```

But it does not make sense in django(of course, I could not understand this because I use english as SECOND LANGUAGE.

Could you give a definition of the word 'render'?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sense 7](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/render#Verb), to transform the template and provided variables for presentation to a user.

Comment: Thank you, I have forgot existence of wiktionary.

Answer (score 3):

In django, *template is rendered to HTTPResponse*. ie the template is interpreted and translated to appropriate output. In django templates can be rendered to http response (`render_to_response`) or string (`render_to_string`).

Few related English word meaning in my dictionary are

```
render:
    give an interpretation or rendition of 
        The pianist rendered the Beethoven sonata beautifully
    restate (words) from one language into another language
        She rendered the French poem into English
```

Answer (score 1):

Render in simple terms means the process of  transforming or translating or turning codes like html, css or Java codes, into interactive pages a website visitor can see or sees when they click on a link or reference link.

Answer (score -1):

To merge your template and code to create a proper page